# How do I iterate over specific rows of a matrix?

Tags: r, loops, matrix, row

I am asking this question again because last time I wasn't clear at all. I have this data:

```
matrix.test = matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), nrow=3, ncol=2)
a <- c(1,5)
```

I would like to run the following formula on only the first and third rows. So row one would be: `sqrt(sum(matrix.test[1,]-a)^2)`, and row 3 would be `sqrt(sum(matrix.test[3,]-a)^2)`. The result of the first equation is 3 and of the second is 4.

But if I had a much larger matrix, how could I tell R to run the equation over specific rows, instead of typing the same equation over and over again into to console? I don't understand how to iterate over specific rows of a matrix. What the output is doesn't really matter. It could a matrix, e.g.

```
      [,1] 
[1,]    3    
[2,]    4
```

Or just a vector, e.g. `[1] 3 4`

Comment: Are you looking for: `apply(matrix.test[c(1,3), ], 1, function(x) sqrt(sum(x - a)^2))`, here substitute `c(1,3)` with the rows you want to apply this to

Comment: why do square and square root?? is your aim to remove the negatives?

Comment: `abs(rowSums(sweep(matrix.test[c(1,3),],2,a)))`

Comment: `abs(colSums(t(matrix.test[c(1,3),])-a))`

Comment: So is it a specific vector of row numbers that you know? Or is there a specific rule for knowing which to calculate on?

Comment: You could also do it if you had everything in a dataframe and some kind of condition to decide which rows you wanted to change, which would then be trivial with dplyr. (Just suggesting an alternative if you don't have to have a matrix).

Comment: sum() does not do what you think it does.

Comment: sum() doesn't do what I want because I messed up the equation. It should be sqrt(sum((matrix.test[1,]-a)^2)) instead of sqrt(sum(matrix.test[1,]-a)^2). But kath's answer works well.

Comment: Okay see below also.  You should be able to edit your question.  But sum on a matrix works differently than on a vector which is one of the complexities ... see below.

Answer (score 0):

Updating with a better answer:

Say you have a vector with the row numbers.
The basic idea is that you can use that vector to indicate the rows e.g.
`matrix.test[c(1,3),]`.
I *think* you want something *like* this:

```
matrix.test.new <- matrix(c(matrix.test[rows,1] - a[1],
                          matrix.test[rows,2] - a[2]),
                          nrow = length(rows), ncol = 2)
sqrt((rowSums(matrix.test.new))^2)
```

Of course you could generate `rows` some other way like test for being odd etc.

However, there are some issues with what you are trying to do. First, you are taking square roots without checking signs.  If you are planning to write for unknown inputs are you always going to know that you have positive results or are you prepared to take NaN as an answer?

Second, the `sum()` function on a matrix may not be doing what you think. So that's what we use `rowSums()`, since it explicitly works on rows not the whole matrix.

However, my example shows you that in R you don't iterate the way that you do in other languages, but the example uses functions that are not going to generate NaN and that work row-wise.

The tricky part was realizing that doing the subtraction changes if you are doing it on a vector (one row of the matrix) versus doing it on the whole matrix. In this case since you know you have exactly two columns I could handle that.  If you had a more complicated case you'd have to come up with a way to do it dynamically.

Comment: This does not even give the desired output

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I won't be square rooting negative values because they are all squared. Secondly, I believe that the sum() does what I want it do. In my example I am basically telling R to give me the sum of `(2-1)^2` and `(1-5)^2`, which is what I want. I just messed up the equation in my post.

Comment: So in a matrix sum() is not vectorized, it actually gives you the sum() of all of the values in the whole matrix.  That's why sumRows() etc were created.  It works differently than in a data frame where sum() fives you the total for the oclumn.

Comment: Also if you have errors in your question, edit the question including the equation and the values you expect to get as a result.